# Is it quicker to set .Net PictureBox.Image from a resource file or from a folder

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, resources

As per the title, is there any difference in performance loading an image from resources rather than a folder in the app directory? eg.

```
PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.MyImage
```

Rather than

```
PictureBox1.ImageLocation = C:\....\Images\MyImage.png
PictureBox1.Load()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a core Windows design property, it makes no real difference.  In both cases it will involve reading the image from disk.  The mechanism is different but outcome is the same.  When you got it embedded as a resource, the image is already mapped into memory through a memory-mapped file.  But the data is not, as soon as you access the resource, you'll trigger a page-fault which gets Windows to read the resource into RAM.  When you read it from a file, you'll use the file system cache.  Which also reads file data into RAM.  It ought to be slightly slower since the file system also has to do the work of finding the file on disk.

When the image needs to be loaded again, for example when you use it in a Paint event handler, then the behavior is identical if the data is still in RAM and didn't get thrown out because another process needed it.  You'll get it without the file being read.  Which makes it notably difficult to profile code like this, you'll always get the happy outcome.

The effort of finding the file tips the balance here, a resource is speedier if it is used rarely.  At the cost of it consuming virtual address space permanently, you never want to put very large images in a resource.  Where "very large" is, say, a dozen megabytes.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that loading an image from resources doesn't require you to hard-code a path into your application. The image will always be there when your app is there if it's in resources. That isn't true if you hard-code a path on disk.

Thus, you should always use resources. I doubt there's any speed difference. And if there is, and you don't think that the inherent advantages of resources outweigh it, I promise that it is negligible and completely irrelevant.

Comment: I was wondering if the resources are loaded into memory with the app as opposed to an external file remaining on the hard disk. Agreed the speed difference is minimal and the other benefits are far more important

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which is faster, measure it! Check time before and after assigning a lot of times.

Normally you would choose resources if the resource doesn't change. It is easier because what happens if you use scenario 2 and the file does not exist?

Comment: That probably won't work, at least it won't give you an accurate number. The image will end up cached and it'll load a lot more quickly after the initial trial.